# postgres copy command using binary field

Tags: postgresql, binary, copy

I would like to use the PostgreSQL copy command were one of the fields is a binary field, which value should I put in the CSV in order to use the copy command from CSV to the new table which has a binary field

Answer (score 1):

On reasonably recent PostgreSQL versions, that would be

```
\xDEADBEEF
```

for a 4-byte `bytea`.